# Dynamically Generating RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm going to generate an `asp:CheckBoxList` using this code

```
<%

System.Collections.Generic.List<QuizzEngine.Common.Question> qList = (System.Collections.Generic.List<QuizzEngine.Common.Question>)Session[QuizzEngine.Common.SessionKeys.QuesionsList];

int navigator = (int)Session[QuizzEngine.Common.SessionKeys.Navigator];

if (True)

{

%>

<'asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblistAnswers" runat="server" 

<'Width="139px"style="text-align: left" AutoPostBack="False">

<'asp:ListItem Value="1">Me<'/asp:ListItem>

<'/asp:CheckBoxList>

<%

cblistAnswers.Items.Clear();

foreach (QuizzEngine.Common.Answer answer in qList[navigator].QuestionAllAnswers)

{
     ListItem i = new ListItem();

     i.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

     i.Value = answer.AnswerId.ToString();

     i.Text = answer.AnswerText;

     cblistAnswers.Items.Add(i);

}

%>
```

Only the `ListItem` I added in the markup :

```
<'asp:ListItem Value="1">Me<'/asp:ListItem>
```

appears, the other items I added dynamically doesn't appear, what I should do?

Comment: How about making your question a bit more readable? Select the block of text and click the 'code' button...

Comment: I'm sorry I forget to ask my question

Comment: Also, your question states you want a RadioButtonList but then create a CheckBoxList

Comment: Thanks anyway I want to do both (RadioButtonList and CheckBoxList), this is what made conflect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Done It**
Just Like reversing **Server-Side-Code to generate items** with **CheckBoxList tag**,
the reason is when executing in my first case adding items to the control comming after rendering it, and this is wrong, First add items to the control then write its tag to render.

**I'm mixing my server-side-code with asp tags to dynamically generate my controls and show them, If any one has another way kindly provide.**

**Thanks All**

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx).  It has all the details you require and samples for creating a CheckBoxList.

Answer (score 0):

netseng, have a look at user-controls, placeholders and dynamic loading of user-controls. i think with both of them you can make your page more dynamic, and, you will get a profit if you can reuse the user-controls!

Answer (score -1):

i'm sure you don't need this:

```
i.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
```